# Spring boot app started in docker can not access environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When i start a spring boot app in the docker i receive an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mail.host' in value "${mail.host}"
```

Without docker the application is starting if i set the variable -Dmail.host to VM arguments.

In the application properties from a spring boot app i have defined some properties like this:

```
spring.mail.host=${mail.host}
spring.mail.port=${mail.port}
spring.mail.username=${mail.from}
spring.mail.from=${mail.from}
spring.mail.password=${mail.password}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.smtp.debug=DEBUG
spring.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=${mail.port}
spring.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
```

The Docker file looks lie this:

```
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar",\
"-Dmail.from=*******",\
"-Dmail.password=******",\
"-Dmail.port=***",\
"-Dmail.host=****",\
"-Dencoder.secrete=*******]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Do not write down environment related variables to Docker file, use docker-compose on target server instead and prevent future headache :)

```
# Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx\${MEM_MAX} -Xms\${MEM_INI} ...."
ADD ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","${JAVA_OPTS}","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Then specify docker-compose.yml file:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"

services:
  application:
    image: your-image:lates
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Prague"
      JAVA_OPTS: >-
        -Dmail.from=*******
        -Dmail.password=******
        -Dmail.port=***"
        -Dmail.host=****"
        -Dencoder.secrete=*******
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that but the application can not start anymore. When the container is starting it says:
`Error: Could not find or load main class ${JAVA_OPTS}`

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way how to set environment variables:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY /target/metal-investment-0.0.1.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
ENV MAIL_FROM=$METAL_INVESTMENT_MAIL_FROM
ENV MAIL_PASSWORD=$METAL_INVESTMENT_MAIL_PASSWORD
ENV MAIL_PORT=$METAL_INVESTMENT_MAIL_PORT
ENV MAIL_HOST=$METAL_INVESTMENT_MAIL_HOST
ENV ENCODER_SECRETE=$METAL_INVESTMENT_ENCODER_SECRETE
```

*The values for variables like this $METAL_INVESTMENT_MAIL_FROM are set in the environment variables from the operating system.